# Unable to copy metadata

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

**BACKGROUND:**

I have the following script which should copy a single file from one location to another and also copy the Modified date metadata.

It all works except it does not copy the modified date metadata and shows the date/time the file was copied across in the modified date metadata field/column:

When I output the source files modified date to the screen, it shows the correct modified date, but that does not seem to get applied to the file in the new location.

---

**SCRIPT:**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Variables for Processing
$WebURL="https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev"
$SourceFile="https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/folder1/user1/test.doc"
$TargetLibrary="folder2"

#Get Objects
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$SourceFile = $Web.GetFile($SourceFile)
$TargetLibrary = $Web.GetFolder($TargetLibrary)

#Copy the file into the Target library
$File = $TargetLibrary.Files.Add($SourceFile.Name, $SourceFile.OpenBinary(), $true)

#Copy Meta-Data
#METADATA UPDATE DOES NOT WORK
$item = $File.Item

#Original attempt - not working
#$item["Modified"] = $SourceFile.TimeLastModified.ToLocalTime()

#Suggested attempt 2 - not working
#$itemModified = ([DateTime]$SourceFile.Item["Modified"]).DateTime 
#$item["Modified"] = $itemModified 

#Suggested attempt 2
$File.item["Modified"] = $SourceFile.item["Modified"]

##Check value of sourcefiles modifieddate - shows correct modified date
write-host $SourceFile.item["Modified"]

#Update
$item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Shows current date as modified date]

However, the write-host shows the correct modified date:

```
PS C:\Users\Oshiro\Desktop\scripts> .\MetaData.ps1
10 August 2018 10:00:07
PS C:\Users\Oshiro\Desktop\scripts>
```

---

**QUESTION:**

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

---

**EXPORT-SPWEB ATTEMPT:**

**Script:**

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/folder1/user1/" -ItemUrl "lists/Customlist" -Path "c:\sharepoint_export\customlist_export.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity
```

**Error:**

```
Export-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPWeb object with Id or Url : https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/folder1/user1/.
At line:1 char:13
+ Export-SPWeb <<<<  -Identity "https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/folder1/user1/" -ItemUrl "lists/Customlist" -Path "c:\sharepoint_export\customlist_export.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletExportWeb:SPCmdletExportWeb) [Export-SPWeb], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletExportWeb
```

Comment: can you replace the last line to `$Item.SystemUpdate()` and check ?

Comment: @GautamSheth,  Just tried your suggestion and it didn't make a difference.  Same issue as before.

Comment: Can you try it as 
`$itemModified = ([DateTime]$SourceFile.Item["Modified"]).DateTime
$item["Modified"] = $itemModified
$item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()`  and check ? Also notice that it needs to be `$item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()` where `i` is lowercase unlike that in your mentioned code

Comment: @GautamSheth,  Done as you suggested, but still not working.  Updated script above to show your suggestions, plus added screenshot of copied file with wrong modifed date, and output showing the date in the `$itemModified` variable, which shows the correct date.  It just doesn't seem to get applied to the new copied file.

Comment: it needs to be `Export-SPWeb -Identity"https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev"`

Answer (score 0):

Your script appears fine to me, only one line should be changed (these columns are usually considered read-only but they can be modified):

```
# new_file["Modified"] = original_file["Modified"]
$File.item["Modified"] = $SourceFile.item["Modified"]
```

You will find some topics concerning this issue.  Some posts will tell you that `export-spweb` and `import-spweb` do not preserve such items as create/modified date, created by, etc. which is now not true.

Besides fixing the line could you check these:

- GUI `IncludeUserSecurity`

Enable `IncludeUserSecurity` via GUI.  You need to: check box on *central administration console*/*Backup Section* -> *'Export Full Security'*

[image: Export Full Security section]

- If you should use Export/Import-SPWeb, there is an option `-IncludeUserSecurity`.

You could script it using [Export-SPWeb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Export-SPWeb?view=sharepoint-ps) and [Import-SPWeb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Import-SPWeb?view=sharepoint-ps) which do contain the parameter `[-IncludeUserSecurity]`

### **Edit - due to comments - using `Export-SPWeb` to export only a list of files**

You can't export, as oshirowanen correctly noted, individual files with Export-SPWeb - you can **only export**: **whole site, list or library**.

I'm including a way how to export/import a list:

Exporting a list via `Export-SPWeb` (site collection is not root):

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/folder1/user1/" -ItemUrl "lists/Customlist" -Path "c:\sharepoint_export\customlist_export.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity
```

**Note:** Don't forget to include the last backslash at the site collection name.

(To create: [a list in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-list-in-sharepoint-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083), to [edit a list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-list-settings-in-sharepoint-online-4d35793b-246e-42a3-990c-563a83795b7f) or create a custom list via [Sharepoint designer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-d0de3aa0-5e70-4ae9-bfd1-7e03a599bc73)).

To import the list should be straightforward:

```
Import-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/folder2/" -Path "c:\sharepoint_export\customlist_export.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity
```

Comment: @turkan,  I chanced that line but it didn't make a difference.  I will now check the central admin settings as suggested.

Comment: @oshirowanen I see it now.  I did not have the page updated when I wrote it.

Comment: No worries.  In Central Admin, where do I find the `IncludeUserSecurity` option?

Comment: @oshirowanen in the Backup section (you should see it same as on the picture - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk1ZU.png)

Comment: @turkan,  Thank you.  I can't seem to check that option without starting an export.  Before the script above, I successfully used Export-SPWeb, but that exports the entire site.  I am trying to copy certain documents within a site document library.  So I don't think Export-SPWeb is the best option.  Unless I can use Export-SPWeb to export only certain documents, and then Import-SPWeb to specific document libraries?  I could be wrong, but as far as I understand, Export/Import-SPWeb can't be used for this purpose, which is why I tried the script above.  Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @oshirowanen I see.  You can export only certain documents via `Export-SPWeb` using a list template.  I'll update the answer, check it then if it suits your need.

Comment: Just tried that, and it is giving me an error.  I have updated the question and added the error at the end.  I thought Export-SPWeb can only take in a SharePoint site as an `-identity`?  So doesn't the error make sense?  `https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/folder1/user1/` is the location of a document library sub folder?

Comment: @oshirowanen Do you have correctly set the content DB rights as in my answer to your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301664/get-spweb-is-unable-to-find-the-object-with-id-or-url/52366075#52366075.  (could you try without the double quotes around the `-identity` URL and the `-ItemUrl`?

Comment: waiting for the server guys to let me know what the contentdatabase is called.

Comment: @oshirowanen so how did it go?